# JPA passing list to IN clause in named native query

Tags: jpa, arraylist, in-clause, nativequery

I know I can pass a list to named query in JPA, but how about NamedNativeQuery? I have tried many ways but still can't just pass the list to a NamedNativeQuery. Anyone know how to pass a list to the in clause in NamedNativeQuery? Thank you very much!

The NamedNativeQuery is as below:

```
@NamedNativeQuery(
   name="User.findByUserIdList", 
   query="select u.user_id, u.dob, u.name, u.sex, u.address from user u "+
         "where u.user_id in (?userIdList)"
)
```

and it is called like this:

```
List<Object[]> userList = em.createNamedQuery("User.findByUserIdList").setParameter("userIdList", list).getResultList();
```

However the result is not as I expected.

```
System.out.println(userList.size());  //output 1

Object[] user = userList.get(0);
System.out.println(user.length);   //expected 5 but result is 3
System.out.println(user[0]);       //output MDAVERSION which is not a user_id
System.out.println(user[1]);       //output 5
System.out.println(user[2]);       //output 7
```

Comment: Have you tried executing exactly the same query using your DB client?

Comment: you should not use bracket (?userIdList) just remove the bracket and it would work

Answer (score 25, accepted):

A list is not a valid parameter for a native SQL query, as it cannot be bound in JDBC.  You need to have a parameter for each argument in the list.

where u.user_id in (?id1, ?id2)

This is supported through JPQL, but not SQL, so you could use JPQL instead of a native query.

Some JPA providers may support this, so you may want to log a bug with your provider.

Comment: Attention: this answer is incorrect. See my answer below and also the references.

Answer (score 53):

**The above accepted answer is not correct and led me off track for many days !!**

> JPA and Hibernate both accept collections in native query using Query.

You just need to do

```
String nativeQuery = "Select * from A where name in :names"; //use (:names) for older versions of hibernate
Query q = em.createNativeQuery(nativeQuery);
q.setParameter("names", l);
```

Also refer the answers here which suggest the same (I picked the above example from one of them)

1. [Reference 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4828203/6043669)
2. [Reference 2 which mentioned which cases paranthesis works which giving the list as a parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21341663/6043669)

*note that these references are about jpql queries, nevertheless the usage of collections is working with native queries too.

Comment: Those are JPA/JPQL queries, not native SQL queries, now are they. The question is about _native queries_, and the accepted answer even calls out that difference, or am I misreading something here?

Comment: "A list is not a valid parameter for a native SQL query" -this is the specific part of the previous answer which is incorrect since lists are allowed in native queries. The query i have given as example is a native query (which is a small part of what i use in my code). It works.

Comment: Your example says `jpql`, it shows a query without `SELECT ...` which makes it invalid native SQL in at least some databases I know, you're using `createQuery` instead of `createNativeQuery`. Maybe we're just not talking about the same thing here. Native == SQL. Your answer == JPQL != SQL.

Comment: I was trying to convey the broad point that it is possible using native queries. I  modified the answer now since some of those parts were probably confusing you. Hope that helps - thanks for the feedback.

Comment: How did you got all the points? The title of the question is about native queries! The code and the links do not help here in any way. Just renaming createQuery to createNativeQuery does not fix the answer.

Comment: Works for me, but only if the list has at least 1 entry.

Comment: This is wrong and it doesn't work. You can do this in JPA/JPQL queries, not native SQL queries like @SanderVerhagen said

Comment: This  doesn't work for native queries for me at all, incorrect answer

Comment: Answer is correct. If it doesn't, then try to display the generated sql into the console. Do NOT USE PARENTHESES AFTER THE 'in' clause like "select * from A where name in (:names)". This does not work!

Answer (score 12):

can be as simple as:

```
@Query(nativeQuery =true,value = "SELECT * FROM Employee as e WHERE e.employeeName IN (:names)")  
 List<Employee> findByEmployeeName(@Param("names") List<String> names);
```

Answer (score 9):

Depending on your database/provider/driver/etc., you can, in fact, pass a list in as a bound parameter to a JPA native query.

For example, with Postgres and EclipseLink, the following works (returning true), demonstrating multidimensional arrays and how to get an array of double precision.  (Do `SELECT pg_type.* FROM pg_catalog.pg_type` for other types; probably the ones with `_`, but strip it off before using it.)

```
Array test = entityManager.unwrap(Connection.class).createArrayOf("float8", new Double[][] { { 1.0, 2.5 }, { 4.1, 5.0 } });
Object result = entityManager.createNativeQuery("SELECT ARRAY[[CAST(1.0 as double precision), 2.5],[4.1, 5.0]] = ?").setParameter(1, test).getSingleResult();
```

The cast is there so the literal array is of doubles rather than numeric.

More to the point of the question - I don't know how or if you can do named queries; I think it depends, maybe.  But I think following would work for the Array stuff.

```
Array list = entityManager.unwrap(Connection.class).createArrayOf("int8", arrayOfUserIds);
List<Object[]> userList = entityManager.createNativeQuery("select u.* from user u "+
     "where u.user_id = ANY(?)")
     .setParameter(1, list)
     .getResultList();
```

I don't have the same schema as OP, so I haven't checked this exactly, but I think it should work - again, at least on Postgres & EclipseLink.

Also, the key was found in: http://tonaconsulting.com/postgres-and-multi-dimensions-arrays-in-jdbc/

Answer (score 9):

Using hibernate, JPA 2.1 and deltaspike data I could pass a list as parameter in query that contains IN clause. my query is below.

```
@Query(value = "SELECT DISTINCT r.* FROM EVENT AS r JOIN EVENT AS t on r.COR_UUID = t.COR_UUID where " +
        "r.eventType='Creation' and t.eventType = 'Reception' and r.EVENT_UUID in ?1", isNative = true)
public List<EventT> findDeliveredCreatedEvents(List<String> eventIds);
```

Answer (score 3):

In jpa, it worked for me

```
@Query(nativeQuery =true,value = "SELECT * FROM Employee as e WHERE e.employeeName IN (:names)")  
List<Employee> findByEmployeeName(@Param("names") List<String> names);
```

Answer (score 2):

currently I use JPA 2.1 with Hibernate

I also use IN condition with native query. Example of my query

```
SELECT ... WHERE table_name.id IN (?1)
```

I noticed that it's impossible to pass String like "id_1, id_2, id_3" because of limitations described by [James](https://stackoverflow.com/users/416206/james)

But when you use jpa 2.1 + hibernate it's possible to pass List of string values. For my case next code is valid:

```
    List<String> idList = new ArrayList<>();
    idList.add("344710");
    idList.add("574477");
    idList.add("508290");

    query.setParameter(1, idList);
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case ( EclipseLink , PostGreSQL ) this works :

```
    ServerSession serverSession = this.entityManager.unwrap(ServerSession.class);
    Accessor accessor = serverSession.getAccessor();
    accessor.reestablishConnection(serverSession);
    BigDecimal result;
    try {
        Array jiraIssues = accessor.getConnection().createArrayOf("numeric", mandayWorkLogQueryModel.getJiraIssues().toArray());
        Query nativeQuery = this.entityManager.createNativeQuery(projectMandayWorkLogQueryProvider.provide(mandayWorkLogQueryModel));
        nativeQuery.setParameter(1,mandayWorkLogQueryModel.getPsymbol());
        nativeQuery.setParameter(2,jiraIssues);
        nativeQuery.setParameter(3,mandayWorkLogQueryModel.getFrom());
        nativeQuery.setParameter(4,mandayWorkLogQueryModel.getTo());
        result = (BigDecimal) nativeQuery.getSingleResult();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new DataAccessException(e);
    }

    return result;
```

Also in query cannot use IN(?) because you will get error like :

> Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: numeric = numeric[]

'IN(?)' must be swapped to '= ANY(?)'

My solution was based on Erhannis concept.

Answer (score 1):

Tried in JPA2 with Hibernate as provider and it seems hibernate does support taking in a list for "IN" and it works. (At least for named queries and I believe it will be similar with named NATIVE queries)
What hibernate does internally is generate dynamic parameters, inside the IN same as the number of elements in the passed in list.

So in you example above

```
List<Object[]> userList = em.createNamedQuery("User.findByUserIdList").setParameter("userIdList", list).getResultList();
```

If list has 2 elements the query will look like

```
select u.user_id, u.dob, u.name, u.sex, u.address from user u "+
         "where u.user_id in (?, ?)
```

and if it has 3 elements it looks like

```
select u.user_id, u.dob, u.name, u.sex, u.address from user u "+
         "where u.user_id in (?, ?, ?)
```

Answer (score 1):

you should do this:

`String userIds ="1,2,3,4,5";`
`List<String> userIdList= Stream.of(userIds.split(",")).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Then, passes like parameter inside your query, like this:

`@NamedNativeQuery(name="User.findByUserIdList", query="select u.user_id, u.dob, u.name, u.sex, u.address from user u where u.user_id in (?userIdList)")`

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible with standard JPA. Hibernate offers the proprietary method `setParameterList()`, but it only works with Hibernate sessions and is not available in JPA's `EntityManager`.

I came up with the following workaround for Hibernate, which is not ideal but almost standard JPA code and has some nice properties to it.

For starters you can keep the named native query nicely separated in a `orm.xml` file:

```
<named-native-query name="Item.FIND_BY_COLORS" result-class="com.example.Item">
    <query>
        SELECT i.*
        FROM item i
        WHERE i.color IN ('blue',':colors')
        AND i.shape = :shape
    </query>
</named-native-query>
```

The placeholder is wrapped in single quotes, so it's a valid native JPA query. It runs without setting a parameter list and would still return correct results when other matching color parameters are set around it.

Set the parameter list in your DAO or repository class:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<Item> findByColors(List<String> colors) {
    String sql = getQueryString(Item.FIND_BY_COLORS, Item.class);
    sql = setParameterList(sql, "colors", colors);

    return entityManager
            .createNativeQuery(sql, Item.class)
            .setParameter("shape", 'BOX')
            .getResultList();
}
```

No manual construction of query strings. You can set any other parameter as you normally would.

Helper methods:

```
String setParameterList(String sql, String name, Collection<String> values) {
    return sql.replaceFirst(":" + name, String.join("','", values));
}

String getQueryString(String queryName, Class<?> resultClass) {
    return entityManager
            .createNamedQuery(queryName, resultClass)
            .unwrap(org.hibernate.query.Query.class) // Provider specific
            .getQueryString();
}
```

So basically we're reading a query string from `orm.xml`, manually set a parameter list and then create the native JPA query. Unfortunately, `createNativeQuery().getResultList()` returns an untyped query and untyped list even though we passed a result class to it. Hence the `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`.

Downside: Unwrapping a query without executing it may be more complicated or impossible for JPA providers other than Hibernate. For example, the following might work for EclipseLink (untested, taken from [Can I get the SQL string from a JPA query object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6276122/can-i-get-the-sql-string-from-a-jpa-query-object/)):

```
Session session = em.unwrap(JpaEntityManager.class).getActiveSession();
DatabaseQuery databaseQuery =     query.unwrap(EJBQueryImpl.class).getDatabaseQuery();
databaseQuery.prepareCall(session, new DatabaseRecord());
Record r = databaseQuery.getTranslationRow();
String bound = databaseQuery.getTranslatedSQLString(session, r);
String sqlString = databaseQuery.getSQLString();
```

An alternative might be to store the query in a text file and add code to read it from there.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass in a list as a parameter, but:

- if you create a `@NamedNativeQuery` and use `.createNamedQuery()`, you don't use named param, you used `?1`(positional parameter). It starts with 1, not 0.
- if you use `.createNativeQuery(String)`, you can use named param.

Answer (score -5):

You can try this **:userIdList** instead of **(?userIdList)**

```
@NamedNativeQuery(
       name="User.findByUserIdList", 
       query="select u.user_id, u.dob, u.name, u.sex, u.address from user u "+
             "where u.user_id in :userIdList"
)
```