# createNativeQuery will not return rows in java but will in db2 sql

Tags: java, jpa, db2, openjpa

Doing the following on the prompt returns one row:

```
asdf@dev:/home/asdf$db2 "select bo_id from (select h.bo_id, max(h.date) as latest from boh h join bo b on h.bo_id = b.id 
where b.code = '625' AND h.status in ('A', 'B') group by h.bo_id) where latest < '2016-03-09'"

bo_id     
1

  1 record(s) selected.
```

But when doing the following java code it will return no rows:

```
String sql = "select bo_id from (select h.bo_id, max(h.date) as latest from boh h join bo b on h.bo_id = b.id where b.code = ? " +
        "AND h.status in (?) group by h.bo_id) where latest < ?";
Query query = em.createNativeQuery(sql);
query.setParameter(1, "625");
query.setParameter(2, statusString);
query.setParameter(3, afterDate);
List<Long> branchOfferIds =  query.getResultList();
```

The row List branchOfferIds =  query.getResultList(); return no rows.
I can not see what I am doing wrong. 
Could anybody please help out?
I am running Linux , java 7 and db2 10.

Comment: What are the values for statusString and afterDate?

Comment: String statusString = "'A','B'"; String afterDate = "'2016-03-09'"; I have tried to remove single quotes but with no luck.

Comment: This wont work, because this is not how you write these quires. This link has the answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6277807/jpa-passing-list-to-in-clause-in-named-native-query