# Native query IN clause throwing sql error

Tags: java, jpa, jpa-2.0

Below query gives me error like `Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 1`
I tried it without brackets in the `IN` parameters like `... WHERE p.SALES_TYPE IN :types`. but still the same error.

```
public List getWithinXDays(ArrayList<String> salesTypes,String sId, String  xdays) {

    Query q  = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT p.ORDER_ID FROM formtable p WHERE p.SALES_TYPE IN (:types) AND p.MCODE=:sid AND TRUNC(SYSDATE - p.creationdate) <=:days");
    q.setParameter("types",salesTypes);
    q.setParameter("sid",sId);
    q.setParameter("days",xdays);
    List salesOrderRow = q.getResultList();
    return salesOrderRow;
}
```

stacktrace :

```
<Jan 10, 2017 4:12:07 PM SGT> <Warning> <EclipseLink> <BEA-2005000> <2017-01-10 16:12:07.551--UnitOfWork(29679273)--Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 1
Error Code: 17041
```

Comment: remove the braces here: `IN (:types)`

Comment: @Jens same error. I tried it also.

Comment: What is the valyue of salesTypes?n is it empty or null

Comment: index 1 should be 'sid' param if im not mistaken. could you check/debug if it's null?

Comment: @geneqew   It's not null. I checked.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JPA passing list to IN clause in named native query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6277807/jpa-passing-list-to-in-clause-in-named-native-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JPA doesn't support `array` parameters for native queries. Either rewrite your code to use JPQL, or set each entry for IN clause like it's described in the following answer: [JPA passing list to IN clause in named native query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6277807/jpa-passing-list-to-in-clause-in-named-native-query)