# How to fetch jsonb column through jpa springboot?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have one table which contains one column 'details' as jsonb data type. The content is

```
{
     "name": "username",
     "value": "user1",
     "is_required": true
}
```

for one row.
I want to write one jpa hibernate query in spring boot to fetch this record when name == username for details column.

Something like this:

```
select details->>'value' from table where details->>'name' = 'username';
```

This syntax does not work in spring boot hibernate query.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use spring data jpa to query jsonb column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43900457/how-do-i-use-spring-data-jpa-to-query-jsonb-column)

Comment: It does not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer. Use

```
@Query(value="select details->>'value' from table where details->>'name' = 'username'", nativeQuery=true)
```