# Spring JPA Specification and JSONB array of strings [Postgres]

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, jpa, jsonb

I'm trying to solve a problem about **JPA Specifications** and use of JSONB *array values*.

Let's say we use Postgres and have a SQL entity like this

```
id character varying(255)
code character varying(255)
data jsonb
```

where in *data* there is a value of this type ["aaa","bbb","ccc"].

In my entity I have:

```
@Entity(name = "my_entity")
@TypeDefs({
        @TypeDef(name = "JsonDataType", typeClass = JsonDataType.class)
})
public class MyEntity {
    @Id
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "code")
    private String code;

    @Type(type = "JsonDataType")
    @Column(name = "data")
    private List<String> data;

    // GETTERS AND SETTERS
```

that is correctly serialized when inserting entity in DB.

It's easy to build a specification to query for *code* attribute, i.e.

```
public static Specification<MyEntity> searchByCode(String code) {
        return (root, criteriaQuery, criteriaBuilder) 
                       -> (code != null) 
                            ? criteriaBuilder.equal(root.<String>get("code"), code) 
                            : null;
}
```

Now I need to use **Specification** to query for a value into *data* json array, that is almost the same of a query like this: **select * from my_entity where data ? 'aaa';**

I cannot find any solution around inet. :(

Can someone give me a clue? Thanks in advance.

Luigi

Comment: While `jsonb` has fairly common support nowadays, I don't believe there are any abstractions when it comes to querying JSON columns. You'd need to invoke a function. Just be aware these are platform specific, so it won't be portable. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43900457/how-do-i-use-spring-data-jpa-to-query-jsonb-column