# How to create a native query in JPA

Tags: postgresql, jpa, jsonb

I have a query that checks if in column jsonb that is List present a string like:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT item FROM catalog_cache WHERE tags ? 'somestring' ", nativeQuery = true)
```

Is there special syntax in JPA for jsonb operations like '?', '?|', '@>'.

Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "$1"

But it doesn't work. Any ideas why?

Comment: What should be the return of the query? Is item a column?

Comment: it returns item. But it doesn't matter cause for JPA '?' is special symbol even if I set it nativeQuery. I need to JPA understand real native SQL JSONB syntax with |?, &?, ?

Answer (score 0):

correct your syntax it will be like this :

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * from catalog_cache WHERE where tags = ?1", nativeQuery = true)
List<CatalogCacheEntity> findWhatEverName(String value);
```

Comment: It doesn't work because tags is JSONB column. Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: jsonb = character varying

Comment: @user3693537 you have to be more specific, but for instance have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43900457/how-do-i-use-spring-data-jpa-to-query-jsonb-column ,  there something called `jsonb_extract_path_text`

Comment: If be more specific: I have a table that contains column jsonb tags. Tags is list structure. [ "x", "y", "z"]. I created index CREATE INDEX catalog_cache_tags_inx ON catalog_cache USING GIN ((tags)); So to work more effective I need execute that query  SELECT * from catalog_cache WHERE where tags ? 'x'. to find all rows where column tags contains 'x'