# Unable to Retrieve JSONB Attribute 'gender' in JPA Query without NativeQuery

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data, jsonb

I'm facing an issue with retrieving a 'gender' attribute from a JSONB column using JPA Query in my Spring Data JPA project. I want to avoid using a native query if possible.
Im using PostgreSQL

**Entity:**

```
@Entity
public class CustomerData {
    
    @Id
    private Long id;
    
    @Type(type = "jsonb")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "jsonb")
    private Map<String, Object> customerData = new HashMap<>();
}
```

**Repository:**

```
public interface CustomerDataRepository extends JpaRepository<CustomerData , Long> {
    @Query("SELECT COUNT(c.id), c.customerData->>'gender' FROM CustomerData c GROUP BY c.customerData->>'gender'")
    String genderStats();
}
```

**Error**

```
unexpected token: > near line 1, column 128 [SELECT cd.customerData FROM models.CustomerData cd GROUP BY cd.customerData->>'gender'
```

Comment: Is there any error or is that column value not being retrieved?

Comment: unexpected token: > near line 1, column 128 [SELECT cd.customerData FROM models.CustomerData cd GROUP BY cd.customerData->>'gender'

Comment: The query in your repository and the one in your logs are different!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I use spring data jpa to query jsonb column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43900457/how-do-i-use-spring-data-jpa-to-query-jsonb-column)