# How to pass arguments in native sql query in Repository file in java?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, orm, repository

This is my query, I have written in Repository file.

```
@Query(value = "select * from A a join B b ON a.allocateBy = b.empNo join D d ON b.departmentName = d.departmentName where a.allocateBy in (:allocateByList)",  nativeQuery = true)

ArrayList<A> findAllByAllocateByIn(@Param("allocateByList") String allocateByList);
```

There are no errors but :allocateByList is not getting data. I have printed the value of allocateByList just before. It has data.

Am I missing Something?

Comment: Why "allocateByList" is a String ? Do you have an example of value for "allocateByList" and for "a.allocateBy" ?

Comment: Thanks Julien.   It is a comma separated String. Example value is 'M06','M81'.

Comment: You can [log your queries with params](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1713464/4778343) and see what's going on.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JPA passing list to IN clause in named native query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6277807/jpa-passing-list-to-in-clause-in-named-native-query)

Answer (score 0):

Change allocateByList to list and use below query

```
@Query(value = "select * from A a join B b ON a.allocateBy = b.empNo join D d ON b.departmentName = d.departmentName where a.allocateBy in ?1",  nativeQuery = true);

ArrayList<PointAllocation> findAllByAllocateByIn(List<String> allocateByList);
```

Comment: It's not working. I am getting empty result.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentionned in your comment, "allocateByList" has, for example, the value "'M06','M81'".

So you are doing the following request:

```
select * 
from A a 
join B b ON a.allocateBy = b.empNo 
join D d ON b.departmentName = d.departmentName
where a.allocateBy in ('''M06'',''M81''')
```

You are looking for a value "a" having an "allocateBy" value at " 'M06','M81' ".

I believe you want one which have either the value "M06" or the value "M81".

So you have to do the following modifications:

1) Modify the type of `allocateByList` from `String` to `List<String>`

2) Format the searched value correctly: you have to split on `,` and then remove the `'` wrapping your values.

So:

```
String allocateByListInitial = "'M06','M81'";

String[] allocateByListSplitted = allocateByListInitial.split(",");

// allocateByListSplitted = ["'M06'", "'M81'"] (with single quote wrapping each value)

List<String> allocateByList = Arrays.stream(allocateByListSplitted)
                                    .map(str -> str.substring(1, str.length() - 1)) // Remove first and last character of the string
                                    .collect(Collectors.toList());

// allocateByList = ["M06", "M81"] (without the single quote)

List<PointAllocation> pointAllocations = myRepo.findAllByAllocateByIn(allocateByList);
```